# mini-profiler-results can't be found when using "popup=1" in querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Follow steps to add profiler to your project
2. The project is in a virtual directory
3. "http://localhost/VirtualDirectory/mini-profiler-results?id=00f8651d-ebbf-443d-b60d-d83f950adf6a&popup=1" can't be found. 404.
4. The URL for "http://localhost/VirtualDirectory/mini-profiler-includes.less?v=2.1.4183.14740" is found and if you take away the "popup=1" from the "mini-profiler-results" URL you don't get a 404.

I'm using the latest as of 6/20/2011 (1.3) using NuGet, MVC3, VS2010, Knockout.js and jQuery 1.5.2.

Anybody have any ideas?

Edit: I've already added this is an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=31).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. I left out a step that was very important.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```